# Laravel oneToMany Insert/Update/Delete

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Есть две таблицы:
User

```
---------
|id|name|
|10|John|
---------
```

Article

```
--------------------
|id|user_id| article|
|21|     10|testName|
|22|     10| testVal|
--------------------
```

В реквесте приходит массив артиклов:

```
article[]
article[1][id] = "21"
article[1][article] = "first"

article[2][article] = "second"
```

Нужно положить их в таблицу, чтобы записи которые есть(если в реквесте пришел id) обновились, у которых нет id создать, а которые не пришли в реквесте удалилить.
На выходе должна получится таблица Article такого вида:

```
--------------------
|id|user_id| article|
|21|     10|   first|
|23|     10|  second|
--------------------
```

Comment: insert into table (id,user_id,article) VALUES (21,10,'first'), (23,10,'second') ,... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=21,user_id=10,article='first' . Потом собрать все id из request в виде такой строки $idsStr = '21,22,23,24'; И написать второй запрос DELETE FROM Article WHERE id NOT IN ($idsStr)..

Про DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE почитайте здесь https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Спасибо! Но интересует именно laravel eloquent, метод вроде saveMany()

Comment: У eloqunt есть такой метод updateOrCreate (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31624875/6120970),С delete думаю разберетесь сами.

Comment: Model :: updateOrCreate (
    ['Primary_key' => 8],
    ['Field' => 'value', 'another_field' => 'другое значение']
);
Поскольку 1-й параметр передает массив полей, которые являются уникальными, или, в вашем случае, первичный ключ. Необязательные поля здесь не имеют никакого смысла, так же как передача чего-либо вместе с PK.

Второй параметр - это массив значений, которые также должны обновляться / создаваться, но игнорироваться в уникальном / pk-поиске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот набросал свою реализацию, если я всё правильно понял, то должно отработать без ошибок:

```
//Вот так выглядит ваш POST как я понял    
$_POST['articles'] = [
        1 => [
            'id' => 21,
            'article' => 'first'
        ],
        2 => [
            'article' => 'second'
        ]
    ];
```

Вот так мы его обрабатываем, собираем записи и обновляем данные через метод `sync`:

```
$articles = [];
foreach ($_POST['articles'] as $data) {
    $attributes = [
        'article' => $data['article']
    ];
    //Проверяем именно так, всякие updateOrCreate и т.п. не подойдут потому что id есть не всегда у вас в запросе и будет ошибка
    if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
        $article = App\Article::where('id', $data['id'])
        ->update($attributes);
    } else {
        $article = App\Article::create($attributes);
    }
    array_push($articles, $article->id);
}
$user = App\User::find(1);
//Метод sync добавит записи которых не было и удалит все те что не указаны в массиве
$user->articles()->sync($articles);
```

Так же вы хотели удалять все записи что не были в запросе, это можно сделать вот так:

```
//Удаляем все записи, которых нет в форме
App\Article::whereNotIn('id', $articles)->delete();
```

Comment: `$user = App\User::findOrFail(1)
$articles = [];
foreach ($_POST['articles'] as $data) {
   $articles[] = $user->articles()->updateOrCreate([
'id' => isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null
], $data)->id;
}
App\Article::whereNotIn('id', $articles)->delete();`
чуть короче

Comment: Да кстати, тоже вариант, если используете PHP 7+ можно переписать "isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null" на "$data['id'] ?? null"